# .oga playback in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to play an audio file with AVAudioPlayer with this code:

```
let urlString = "http://192.168.1.19:8080/download/2"
let url = URL(string: urlString)!
print("the url = \(url)")

do {
    let data = try Data.init(contentsOf: url)
    self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer.init(data: data)
    self.audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()

    self.audioPlayer.play()
} catch {
    print("couldn't load file")
}
```

audio format is Oga (.oga) and it always failed to load. Any solution to play this .oga file?

Comment: use VLC https://code.videolan.org/videolan/VLCKit
there is probably a cocoa pod. Just make sure you look at the license.